# Ruby - :: in class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, syntax, module

I'm working with some legacy RoR code, which has four related classes, each defined in its own file.  All of these classes are parser classes, and live in app/models/parsers.  Each file name ends with _parser.rb.

Here's an example class def line from file adf_parser.rb:

```
class Parsers::AdfParser
```

I'm lost as to what the Parsers:: part of that is doing.

- There's no explicit module called Parsers defined anywhere that I can find.
- I don't see any documentation about implicitly creating modules just by adding module specifications to class names.
- The only external dependency is "require 'csv'".
- There are include statements within the class def, but I don't think they have anything that would explain the class name.
- I created a new RoR test project and put stubs of these files in a parallel directory, and they won't run from the command line due to a
  name error.
- I don't see any examples online of classes named in this way.

I'm sure this isn't rocket surgery, but I've lost most of my morning trying to figure this out, and I'd love it if someone could just tell me what's going on with it.

Update:  It sounds like this is just a bit of Rails magic, based on the subdirectory name.  I think the reason that I got an error in my test app is that I just ran the files through the ruby interpreter, rather than invoking them with Rails in some way.

Comment: It's just a namespace. What are you trying to figure out?

Comment: What is the error you get in the command line? Like @DaveNewton said it's just a namespace. You could make it My::Fancy::Parsers::AdfParser if you wanted, but that is how you would have to access it that way every time.

Comment: @Dave yes, but the namespace must be defined somewhere. I think the OP is saying they can't find the definition of the `Parsers` module so is wondering if something special is going on.

Comment: I believe mikej is right; if I understand correctly, the OP is reasonably wondering why these class definitions don't produce a NameError, as `class Foo::Bar;end` does in irb (at least in 1.9.3-p392)

Comment: Right - I don't see a Parsers module defined anywhere.  Is a namespace different than a module?  Would it need a definition file of some sort?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`class Parsers::AdfParser` is in practice equivalent to:

```
module Parsers
  class AdfParser
```

For this to work properly, and the file to be autoloaded its location should be parsers/adf_parser.rb, whether under app/models or lib. Basically the file path needs to mimic the class hierarchy.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but when I created a new dummy project, and tried to put in similar class defs under a parsers folder, I got a name error.  Do the class files have to be created through rails to make this work?

Comment: I tried this myself in `lib/` and it didn't work, hence my incorrect answer (which I've since voted to delete).  As soon as I tried some directory namespacing like this in `app/models/` it all worked.  Neat.

Comment: Classes don't need to be created through rails generators. However they need to be under a path the Rails automatically loads, which is set in config/application.rb. Typically you will have `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]` and same for lib. Then you can write things like `Parser.adfParser.new`

Answer (score 3):

It's in the `parsers` sub-directory of modules; Rails namespaces for you by convention.

Comment: @user1476065 As Dave Said since all ur file are inside 'parsers` subdirectory and Rails namespace it